# PHP to remove last line of CSV file

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

still struggling with PHP and CSV file manipulation. I will try to ask this properly so I can get some help.

I have a CSV file with about 4000 lines/rows, and I wrote this code to create an array of the entire CSV, and pull the the LAST line of the CSV file out to use in my script. The code works to to all this wit success.

```
// CREATE ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY FROM LAST ROW OF CSV FILE
$csv = array();
if (FALSE !== $handle = fopen("Alabama-TEST.csv", "r"))
{
while (FALSE !== $row = fgetcsv($handle))
{
 $csv[] = $row; 
}
}
$new_csv = array();
foreach ($csv as $row)
{
$new_row = array();
for ($i = 0, $n = count($csv[0]); $i < $n; ++$i)
{
$new_row[$csv[0][$i]] = $row[$i]; 
}
$new_csv[] = $new_row;
}
```

The variable $new_row is the last row in the CSV and I am able to use the data fine. But when the script is finished running I want to delete this last row called $new_row.

Here is an example of my CSV file at the top view;

```
CITY        ADDRESS        STATE      NAME
Birmingham  123 Park St.   Alabama    Franky
```

So I just want to remove the last row and keep the header at the top, for the next time the script runs. I've been trying for 3 days solid trying to figure this out, so I'm hoping some kind person who KNOWS WHAT THEY ARE DOING can help.

Here is the code I have tried to remove the last row;

```
$inp = file('Alabama-TEST.csv');
$out = fopen('Alabama-TEST.csv','w');
or ($i=0;$i<count($inp)-1;$i++)
fwrite($out,$inp[$i]);
fclose($out);
```

Since I'm using a large file at around 4000 rows, is there a way to do this without using too much memory?

Comment: Since $n holds the the number of rows, why doesn't "$i < $n - 1" solve it? might it be that you didn't explain yourself correctly?

Comment: The code I showed works to get the variable $new_row perfectly, so nothing wrong with it - I'm looking for away to remove last row before the script runs again. I was assuming that by removing $new_row that would do it. I will add above the code I have tried to remove the last row.

Comment: Do you mean you want to write a new version of Alabama-TEST.csv without the last line?

Comment: @nrathaus - Yes, that is exactly what I am trying to do.

Comment: http://www.hashbangcode.com/blog/remove-last-line-file-php-478.html Perhaps this helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [array_pop](https://www.php.net/array_pop) on your array ($new_csv) and [fputcsv](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) to save the file:

```
array_pop($new_csv); // Removes the last element in the array
$out = fopen('Alabama-TEST-new.csv','w');
foreach ($new_csv as $row) { // sorry for writing it badly, try now
 fputcsv($out, $row);
}
fclose($out);
```

I don't have an environment to test this, sorry.

Comment: Thanks - tried it and it ran with no errors - unfortunately it didn't delete the last row in the CSV - I think you are really close though because it did not mangle the CSV file in anyway.

Comment: Did you notice that I intentionally edited **Alabama-TEST-new.csv** and not the original file? :)

Comment: Sorry - I didn't use Alabama-TEST-new.csv - I'll try again

Comment: I did that to prevent overwriting your original file, did you use the same filename saw no modification?

Comment: Good one! That new file is perfect. Only issue is I want to run the script a second time using the new CSV, and again, again...

Comment: Yes - I ran the script again and using the orginal Alabama-TEST.csv so of course it still had the last line. Man... we're on the verge of solving it. So I DO want to overwrite the original file. I have it backed up - thanks for this.

Comment: So either change the output filename, there shouldn't be any race condition, or use the current filename and then call the rename() function

Comment: Never used the rename() function - what would that look like in this case??

Comment: rename('Alabama-TEST-new.csv', 'Alabama-TEST.csv'), but as mentioned you might not need to do that, did you try to open and save to the same filename?

Comment: I changed the file name - it works!!!!!!!!!!!!! Thanks SO SO SO SO  much for your help - you stuck with me on this to the end!!